# Finding same output values by varying input values of function

Tags: performance-tuning, algorithm

I have written a function in *Mathematica* that needs five input variables.
The function outputs a single real number. The underlying model is a complex model for option pricing. To ease things up, let me define it in a similar way with the built-in `FinancialDerivative` function (Black-Scholes model) instead of my model:

```
calcImpVol[Maturity_, riskfree_, v1_, v2_, v3_] := 
FinancialDerivative[{"European", "Call"}, {"StrikePrice" -> v1, 
"Expiration" -> Maturity, 
"Value" -> v3}, {"InterestRate" -> riskfree, 
"CurrentPrice" -> v2, "Dividend" -> 0.0}, "ImpliedVolatility"];
```

The values of Maturity and riskfree are fixed: Maturity = 2 and riskfree = 0.03.
furthermore, v1 and v2 can be any positive real number and 0$ \leq $v3 $\leq$ v2.

I would like to find all values of v1, v2, and v3 for which the output values of `calcImpVol`are more or less the same for the given input values, i.e.
 differ with a maximum of 0.5 from a target value: [`targetOutput`-.5,`targetOutput`+.5].

I want to use *Mathematica* to iterate in an efficient way to find values of the other three variables, v1 - v3, that yield the required results. I would like to store all of these combinations of the four variables, along with the respective `calcImpVol`value.

I could think of using loops by iterating over all combinations of v1 - v3 using `Tuples` and then manually keep all combinations that output results in the target interval. This process would takes hours, so there's got to be a smarter way. Could anyone help me with an efficient implementation of this problem?

Comment: can the function be rewritten as MyFunc[v1_, v2_,g_] where g is equal to Total[ v3_, v4_, v5_, v6_]?

Comment: More generally, are there any constraints on the input variables? You talk about `Tuples`, does that mean that only discrete values are allowed? Without more information it might be impossible to help you. (Consider for example a function with chaotic behavior - there is no way to achieve what you're after in this case)

Comment: I have edited the question. This should give more information about what I want to achieve.

Comment: If v2 is positive, do you mean $0\le v3 \le v2$?

Comment: Excuse me, I made a typo there. You are correct, I have edited the question